# AJAX + RAILS Problem with ShowTooltip window effect...Routing Error in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

AJAX + RAILS Question.  Am getting a Routing error for the following:

```
<div class="card-field">
  <h6><imgsrc="/images/red_icon.png" width="16" alt="" align="absmiddle" class="image-3"  onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'/quickadd_notes_help.html.erb?ranId='+Math.random(),this,'','');return false;"  /></h6>
 <p>Company Name:</p>
 <input type="text" name="company" id="company" size="50" />
 </div>

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/quickadd_notes_help.html.erb" with {:method=>:post}):
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Both my controller and view are working fine when I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/cats
http://localhost:3000/cats/quickadd_notes_help
```

I've tried modifying my HTML in several ways!

```
window.event,'/quickadd_notes_help.html.erb?ranId='...
window.event,'/quickadd_notes_help?ranId='...
window.event,'/quickadd_notes_help.html?ranId='...
```

I have this same example working fine in a hosted non-Rails environment.  But cannot seem to get this to work inside a Rails environment.  My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
map.resources :cat
```

Appreciate any help you can offer!

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

The action is `/quickadd_notes_help`, not `/quickadd_notes_help.html.erb`

```
<div class="card-field">
  <h6><imgsrc="/images/red_icon.png" width="16" alt="" align="absmiddle" class="image-3"  onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'/quickadd_notes_help?ranId='+Math.random(),this,'','');return false;"  /></h6>
 <p>Company Name:</p>
 <input type="text" name="company" id="company" size="50" />
</div>
```

Also, you should use Rails helpers whenever applicable to generate paths.
Assuming the route is called `quickadd_notes_help`

```
<div class="card-field">
  <h6><imgsrc="/images/red_icon.png" width="16" alt="" align="absmiddle" class="image-3"  onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'<%= quickadd_notes_help_path %>?ranId='+Math.random(),this,'','');return false;"  /></h6>
 <p>Company Name:</p>
 <input type="text" name="company" id="company" size="50" />
</div>
```